# Teradata Change format of Week Number

Tags: sql, date, teradata

I'm pretty new to SQL so I hope this isn't a dumb question, tried to google but couldn't find anything.

I'm summing sales of departments per week in SQL and am using  `TD_SYSFNLIB.WEEKNUMBER_OF_YEAR (trans_dt)` to get the week number.

I think everything is working except I'd like to change the format of the weeks to the start date of the week, e.g. week 1 = 1/4/15

Also, i'm not sure how to handle the very first of the year week 0 since I think that should be grouped up with week 52 of last year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following date math trick should get you Beginning of Week as an actual date without having to join to the SYS_CALENDAR view or using a function:

```
SELECT CURRENT_DATE - ((CURRENT_DATE - DATE '0001-01-07) MOD 7) AS BOW;
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This is perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with TD14 there's `NEXT_DAY` which returns the *following* weekday, if you subtract 7 days you get the previous day:

```
next_day(trans_dt - 7, 'sunday')
```

Comment: It's getting difficult to keep up with the expansion of functions supported in Teradata recently. They are adding them so quickly you almost need a quick reference card to keep track. :)